# Show progress of downloading items in second column of listview c#

Tags: c#, listview

I am creating a Downloader in c# in which the file URL will be placed in first column of listview control. now what i want is to show progress of each downloading item in second column of listview but i am unable to update them as progress change. i don't know how can i use progresschange event for url into listview i am using a foreach loop and creating progresschange event in foreach loop. what i want is similer to IDM.

> Picture. As shown in this the status of downlaod

[image]

Comment: You have to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is a `ProgressBar` you can use in your `ListView`'s `DataTemplate`, in which you can bind the `Value` property to your items' download progress - but you do have to have a progress property in the class containing downloadable items, and - moreover - both the classes (the downloadable item class and its collection view model) should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notify UI on that change (so the XAML side will automatically update the view as progres changes).

As comment said: that would be hard to implement using code if we don't see your current code.